# Asp.net login users with digits number

Tags: asp.net-membership

By default, Membership API uses a separate username field to login users. I would like to use digits numbers for users to login. Like Account Number.

How would I modify the Login.

Answer (score 0):

You can create usernames with all numbers in them, like `123456`, so just create your usernames equal to your account numbers.